# Cannot connect to Linux VM (Google Cloud Platform Compute Engine)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am running a ubuntu 18.04 VM on google cloud platform. I have had it working but now when I try to connect I get this error:

[image: error]

I am unsure what to do about this problem.

Comment: Access the serial port from the Google Cloud Console or via gcloud. Then look at the logs and see if there is an error. I would reboot the instance first. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a firewall rule that allows `tcp:22`

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's related your firewall configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already tried using gcloud, double checked firewall rule and I suspect you did not change anything in the VM configuration, the easiest approach that you can do now is create a snapshot and move it to a new VM instance:

1. Go to Compute Engine section.
2. Then select “Snapshots” in the left menu.
3. Click “Create Snapshot”.
4. In “source disk” select your current VM instance, Encryption: automatic and provide the required information in the other fields.
5. Click “Create”.

After the snapshot is created you can go and use it to create a new VM. In the “Create instance” section do the following:

1. In “Boot Disk” click the “Change” button.
2. Click the “Snapshots” tab (upper right).
3. Select the previously created snapshot.
4. Click “select” and then “Create”.

You should be able to SSH into the new instance.